# How can I make this suitescript loop complete faster

Tags: javascript, loops, netsuite

I have a script that performs a saved search and then adds the results as line items in a sales order. The script does what it is supposed to do but it takes a while to finish executing. In my test example I have 12 line items that are found and loaded into the sales order but it is taking about 5 minutes to completely execute. I am fairly new at the whole looping thing so I am sure my code below is not the best way to do this. Is there a better way to do this:

```
 var mySearch = search.create({
   type: "vendorbill",
   filters:
   [
      ["type","anyof","VendBill"], 
      "AND", 
      ["custcol_twi_line_field_vendor_inv_bk","anyof","27604"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({name: "mainname", label: "Vendor"}),
      search.createColumn({
         name: "internalid",
         join: "vendor",
         label: "Vendor ID"
      }),
      search.createColumn({
         name: "itemid",
         join: "item",
         label: "Item"
      }),
      search.createColumn({
         name: "internalid",
         join: "item",
         label: "Internal ID"
      }),
      search.createColumn({name: "memo", label: "Description"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "quantity", label: "Quantity"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "currency", label: "Currency"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "rate", label: "Rate"})
   ]
});
            var result = mySearch.run().getRange(0, 1000);
            var vendor = new Array();
            var item = new Array();
            var memo = new Array();
            var quantity = new Array();
            var currency = new Array();
            var rate = new Array();
            var x;
            var y;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                vendor.push(result[i].getValue({ name: 'internalid', join: 'vendor' }));
                item.push(result[i].getValue({ name: 'internalid', join: 'item' }));
                memo.push(result[i].getValue({ name: 'memo' }));
                quantity.push(result[i].getValue({ name: 'quantity' }));
                currency.push((parseFloat(result[i].getValue({ name: 'currency' }))));
                rate.push(result[i].getValue({ name: 'rate' }));               

            for (x of item) {
            rec.selectNewLine({ //add a line to a sublist
                sublistId: 'item'      //specify which sublist
            });

            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'item',
                value: x,  //replace with item internal id
                forceSyncSourcing: true
            });
            }
            for (y of memo) {
                rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'description',
                value: y,  //replace with item internal id
                forceSyncSourcing: true
            });
            }
            for (w of currency) {
                rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custcol_currency',
                value: w,  //replace with item internal id
                forceSyncSourcing: true
            });
            }
            for (v of rate) {
                rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custcol_unit_cost_fx',
                value: v,  //replace with item internal id
                forceSyncSourcing: true
                });
            }
       
            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'amount',
            value: 1.00,
            forceSyncSourcing: true
            });
            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'costestimatetype',
            value: "CUSTOM",
            forceSyncSourcing: true
            });
            rec.commitLine({"sublistId": "item"});       
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to check when trying to understand why your script takes a long time is to try and identify which part of the script is taking the longest to run. There are two sections to your code snippet :

1. Doing the search
2. Populating the record

Depending on whether this is client side or server side, this can be done by using console.log or Log.debug to write the current time out.

With the way the code was laid out after the search, it's :
a) creating all the lines and setting the item.
b) looping through all the fields and pushing a value in to each line, and forcing a refresh after each field update.

I've modified the code to :
a) do the search
b) loop through each row and fully populate the record a line at a time without forcing a sync.

There's likely to be an overhead (in time) to jumping from one line to the next, which is happening **i x 4** times. The modified code only does this **i** times.  Another overhead is in the forced syncing. The option forces any empty fields to be collected back from the server to be populated. Again this has come down from **i x 4** times to **i** times.

```
var mySearch = search.create({
    type: "vendorbill",
    filters:
        [
            ["type", "anyof", "VendBill"],
            "AND",
            ["custcol_twi_line_field_vendor_inv_bk", "anyof", "27604"]
        ],
    columns:
        [
            search.createColumn({ name: "mainname", label: "Vendor" }),
            search.createColumn({
                name: "internalid",
                join: "vendor",
                label: "Vendor ID"
            }),
            search.createColumn({
                name: "itemid",
                join: "item",
                label: "Item"
            }),
            search.createColumn({
                name: "internalid",
                join: "item",
                label: "Internal ID"
            }),
            search.createColumn({ name: "memo", label: "Description" }),
            search.createColumn({ name: "quantity", label: "Quantity" }),
            search.createColumn({ name: "currency", label: "Currency" }),
            search.createColumn({ name: "rate", label: "Rate" })
        ]
});
var result = mySearch.run().getRange(0, 1000);
var vendor;
var item;
var memo;
var quantity;
var currency;
var rate;
// var x;
// var y;
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    vendor = result[i].getValue({ name: 'internalid', join: 'vendor' });
    item = result[i].getValue({ name: 'internalid', join: 'item' });
    memo = result[i].getValue({ name: 'memo' });
    quantity = result[i].getValue({ name: 'quantity' });
    currency = result[i].getValue({ name: 'currency' });
    rate = result[i].getValue({ name: 'rate' });

    rec.selectNewLine({ //add a line to a sublist
        sublistId: 'item'      //specify which sublist
    });

    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        value: vendor,
        forceSyncSourcing: true
    });

    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'description',
        value: memo
    });

    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'custcol_currency',
        value: currency
    });

    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({   //set item field
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'custcol_unit_cost_fx',
        value: rate
    });


    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'amount',
        value: 1.00
    });
    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'costestimatetype',
        value: "CUSTOM"
    });
    rec.commitLine({ "sublistId": "item" });
}
```